# Winforms - applying MeasureItem & DrawItem events for only one combo box column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I am working on a winforms project that contains a data grid view which has two combo box columns.
My goal is to make the first combo box column show specific items that match with certain condition.

I researched the topic and found that I need to listen to DataGridView's EditingControlShowing event to detect when the user opens a combo box for display.
Then I need to cast the sender object to ComboBox object and listen to MeasureItem & DrawItem events.
Now, I'll be able to draw the items that meet the condition and hide the rest.

Here are my source links: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237290/filter-on-combobox-based-on-another-combobox-with-same-table-data-in-c-sharp), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290563/create-winforms-combobox-with-non-selectable-items), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445125/disabling-particular-items-in-a-combobox), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758727/how-to-hide-specific-item-from-a-combo-box-in-win-forms)

First, here's my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn first_column = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

            first_column.Name = "First";

            first_column.Items.Add("A");
            first_column.Items.Add("B");
            first_column.Items.Add("C");
            first_column.Items.Add("D");

            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(first_column);

            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn second_column = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

            second_column.Name = "Second";

            second_column.Items.Add("1");
            second_column.Items.Add("2");
            second_column.Items.Add("3");
            second_column.Items.Add("4");

            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(second_column);

            dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing;
        }

        private void DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;

            if (comboBox != null && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
            {
                comboBox.DrawItem -= ComboBox_DrawItem;
                comboBox.DrawItem += ComboBox_DrawItem;

                comboBox.MeasureItem -= ComboBox_MeasureItem;
                comboBox.MeasureItem += ComboBox_MeasureItem;

                comboBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
            }
        }

        private void ComboBox_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl comboBox && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
            {
                if (!canDraw(e.Index))
                {
                    e.ItemHeight = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        private void ComboBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl comboBox && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
            {
                if (canDraw(e.Index))
                {
                    Brush foregroundBrush = Brushes.Black;
                    e.DrawBackground();
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(comboBox.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, foregroundBrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
                    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
                }
            }
        }

        private bool canDraw(int index)
        {
            return index > -1 && index % 2 == 0;
        }
    }
```

Second, I can see the wanted result when I interact with the first column.
For example:
[image]

But the problem starts when I'm interacting with the second column which should display all the items:

[image]

I believe that reason for this problem is having the MeasureItem & DrawItem callback methods being invoked when the user is using the second combo box column.

My question is:
How can I apply the logic above only for the first combo box column while keeping the original implementation for the second combo box column intact?

Thank you.

Comment: The underlying ComboBox Control is the same (it's recycled, for efficiency reasons) -- You don't need to draw the items, just filter the collection - that you can set as the DataSource - based on your criteria

Comment: What's the task here? To **filter** ? Then this is not the way to do it. Bind the ComboBox to a data source such as `DataTable` or `BindingSource`, each of which provides a _filter_ property that you just need to set. `DataTable.DataView.RowFilter` and `BindingSource.Filter` respectively.

Comment: Correction: `DataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter`.